# Как объединить два потока аудио в реальном времени?

Tags: android, аудио

Получаю с помощью `AudioRecord` от диктофона поток аудио в виде массива `short array[]`. Пробовал этот массив записывать в память с разрешением `.pcm`. Воспроизвести получилось его на компьютере с помощью программы `Audacity` указав свойства аудио, так как нет заголовков.

Во время его получения в реальном времени нужно его объединять с фоновой музыкой и записать в файл. (Желательно в `mp3`). Есть идеи как это можно сделать?

Comment: подписываюсь мне также это интересно

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25851484/3069565 посмотрите этот ответ.

Comment: @eugeneek спасибо за ответ. Да декодировать фоновую музыку, если она например в mp3 нужно будет, во всем остальном как я понял в ответе предлагается именно воспроизведение двух записей, что не подходит. Сейчас думаю попробовать суммировать массивы примерно таким способом http://rsdn.org/forum/media/2627745.hot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данный момент сделал следующим образом:

1. Получаю массив байтов 10 секундного фона из `wav` файла
2. Также `wav` файл можно просмотреть на компьютере в `Hex Editor Neo`, в которой можно увидеть значения в десятичной системе исчисления , а так же их значения в кодировки `ASCII` (Так хранится `wav` данные используя контейнер `RIFF`, правда например частота дискретизации не совпадает со значениями в аудио-плеерах, если брать примеры аудио)
3. Настраиваю получение аудио с диктофона с такими же настройками, как и сам аудио файл
4. Далее по необходимости можно прочитать информацию о `wav` файле согласно [его структуре](http://microsin.net/programming/pc/wav-format.html).
5. После нахожу среди этого массива, именно поток с аудио данными. Для этого нам нужно найти название секции `data` которая занимает 4 байта, после нее идут 4 байта в десятичной системе исчисления с размером потока аудио в байтах (у меня этот размер так же не совпадает пока), после них идет массив сигнала. Поиск индекса первого значения с аудио данными:

   ```
   private int readStreamIndex(byte[] backgroundBytes) {
       int startIndex = 0;
       for (int i = 0; i < backgroundBytes.length && i < 100; i++) {
           if (backgroundBytes[i] == 100 && backgroundBytes[i + 1] == 97 && backgroundBytes[i + 2] == 116
                   && backgroundBytes[i + 3] == 97) {
               startIndex = i;
               break;
           }
       }

       return startIndex + 8;//4 байта - название сегмента + 4 байта размер сегмента
   }
   ```
6. В следующем шаге складываю к байтам фона, байты аудио с микрофона полученные от `AudioRecord` и записываю в файл (То есть заголовок объединенного `wav` файла остается от фонового, но можно и свой указать)
7. Проигрываю wav
8. Вместо того что бы записывать в wav, можно с помощью `MediaCodec` кодировать в `aac` и сохранять в файл `m4a` c помощью `MediaMuxer`